# Swift May I know How this same thing happens?

Tags: ios, swift

Can I know how we can do this in swift ?

[Sort NSArray of custom objects based on sorting of another NSArray of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469667/sort-nsarray-of-custom-objects-based-on-sorting-of-another-nsarray-of-strings/24555143#24555143)

I tried with swift's methods

> *reduce*, *filter*, *map*

But I am not getting result

Comment: Read documentation. For example «array.map({ number in 3 * number })» will multiple all objects in array. Or «sort([1, 5, 3, 12, 2]) { $0 > $1 }»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just converted that code to Swift"

```
func customSortFunction() {
    var firstArray:Array = ["12","10","2"]

    var attribute1 = Attribute(assetID: "10")

    var attribute2 = Attribute(assetID: "2")

    var attribute3 = Attribute(assetID: "12")

    var secondArray = [attribute1, attribute2, attribute3]

    secondArray.sort( { (find(firstArray, $0.assetID!))! < (find(firstArray, $1.assetID!))! } )

    println("\(secondArray[0].assetID), \(secondArray[1].assetID), \(secondArray[2].assetID)")

}
```

Attribute class:

```
class Attribute {
var assetID: String?

init(let assetID:String) {
    self.assetID = assetID
}
```

}