# Sort NSPredicate with in clausule with array's order

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `NSPredicate`that does a search of id within an `NSArray`of ids,
something like

`('id in %@',array)`

Is there a way to get the resultset of that fetch sorted with the same array's order?

The code I have now is

```
+(NSArray*)     findIn:(NSArray*)identifiers{

    if(identifiers == nil) return nil;

    NSPredicate *searchFilter   = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", identifiers];
    NSArray     *fetchedObjects =  [GSBaseModel setupFetch:[[self class] managedObjectEntityName] andFilter:searchFilter andSortKey:nil];

    if([fetchedObjects count] == 0){
        return nil;
    }
    return fetchedObjects;
}
```

The setupfecth just does the following:

```
NSFetchRequest      *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity   = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
return  = [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: what do you mean sorted by the same arrays order? You mean sort by id?

Comment: my array is an array of ids already sorted, for example [3,5,1,2,4] so I need the fetched results to be in that order as well

Comment: are you using core data? Because then you can use a sort descriptor.  otherwise there are countless ways to sort an array

Comment: Yes I'm using core data, I'm gonna check what a sort descriptor is

Comment: Have you tried it, I expect it to be sorted (assuming your source object really is an `NSArray`). It would be a good idea to show some actual code...

Comment: Yes, I tried it but they are not sorted, just updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally soved it this way

Thanks to [Sort NSArray of custom objects based on sorting of another NSArray of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469667/sort-nsarray-of-custom-objects-based-on-sorting-of-another-nsarray-of-strings)

```
+(NSArray*)sortWithArray:(NSArray*)toSort sorted:(NSArray*)sortedIdentifiers{
    NSMutableArray *sorted = [NSMutableArray array];

    // pre-populate with objects
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedIdentifiers.count; i++)
    {
        [sorted addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    // place the items at the correct position
    for (NSManagedObject *a in toSort)
    {
        NSNumber* identifier = [a valueForKey:@"id"];
        NSUInteger idx = [sortedIdentifiers indexOfObject:[identifier stringValue]];
        if (idx != NSNotFound)
        {
            [sorted setObject:a atIndexedSubscript:idx];
        }
    }
    // finally remove all the unecesarry placeholders if one array was smaller
    [sorted removeObject:[NSNull null]];
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Thats terribly inefficient, no need to sort when you can use a dictionary. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch core data objects and link them up with an array of id's you should consider using the ever so powerful NSDictionary:

So once you have fetched all your objects simply store those objects in a dictionary keyed by id:

```
NSDictionary *managedObjectsKeyedByID = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:fetchedObjects forKeys:[fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"identifier"]];
```

Now you can iterate over your array and check for matches using your dictionary:

```
for (NSString *identifier in arrayOfServerIDs) {
    NSManagedObject *existingObject = managedObjectsKeyedByID[identifier];
    if(!existingObject) {
       //insert a new one
    } else {
       //update
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will return sorted by id not by my array's order

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol but then what is your arrays order? why sort an already sorted array?

Comment: I have an array of sorted ids, then I need to do a fetch over the core data with those ids, but that result is sorted randomly, what I need is to have the same order as my id's array

Comment: why do they need to be sorted? Why not just put your core data results in a dictionary keyed by id? let me update my answer