# NSCompoundPredicate subpredicate order as called

Tags: objective-c, swift, nspredicate

I am using `NSCompoundPredicate` with `orPredicateWithSubpredicates`. What I want is that, the order at the end should be the order I do subpredicates. What I do is:

```
predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10091"];
predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10088"];
predicate3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10111"];
predicate4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10022"];
predicate5 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10022"];
predicate6 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10068"];
predicate7 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", @"10013"];


finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2, predicate3, predicate4, predicate5, predicate6, predicate7]];
classesArray = [classesArray2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:finalPredicate];
```

In this way it is auto sorting the result by `id`. What I want is to get the array as my call order, not sorted by anything. How can I do that?

Comment: A predicate is for *filtering* the result set, not for sorting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort NSPredicate with in clausule with array's order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989573/sort-nspredicate-with-in-clausule-with-arrays-order)